# Deploy config files along with exes and dlls on windows CE device

Tags: c#, windows-ce

Currently I am deploying my windows CE application on windows CE platform from vs 2008. It is running fine.

My only problem is I want to deploy config files along with exes and dlls.
Currently when I deploy, only exes and dlls are deployed but not the config files.

Properties for each config files are "Content" and "Copy always".

Please help how can I deploy config files as well?

Comment: Are the config-file in the bin-folder after you build?

Answer (score 2):

In your Solution Explorer, right-click the config file that you want to deploy and select properties. In the properties window, select '`Copy Always`' in '`Copy to Output Directory`'

In your deployment project, make sure you include the folder where you've saved the config files. [This link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/z11b431t(v=vs.100).aspx) explains how to add items to your deployment

[image: Snapshot from IDE]

**Note**: If you are using `Publish` from your solution explorer, then select `Build Action` as `None` and `Copy to Output Directory` as `Do not copy`

Comment: Thanks S.Krishna, your help for creating deployment project and adding files to it is very helpful. But I have not created deployment project, I want to directly deploy from vs 2008